# How to create new line in script without error

Tags: r

This is the shorten version of my code in `R` running against the `nycflights13` package:

```
flights %>% group_by(origin, dest) 
%>% summarise(total = sum(flight))
```

If I try to run it, it gives me an error:

```
> %>% summarise(total = sum(flight))
Error: unexpected SPECIAL in "%>%"
```

I know it is due to the new line but I really need a new line as the code was getting too long in the script for one line.

I have seen others do this in their `RStudio` editors and the code should look like this which allows `RStudio` to recognise it and run it properly:

[image]

I tried to make it look like that with tab but it still gives me the error. Does anyone know how I can make a new line in `RStudio` without the error?

Comment: Just move the `%>%` at the end of the  line and not at the beginning. In this way, the parser knows the command isn't finished and look at the next line.

Comment: Thanks - you were actually right. That was silly of me. I didn't even see that on the original screenshot.

Comment: The line has to end in something that makes R expect further input, eg the piping operator in your example.

Comment: @nicola I was still typing while you posted your comment. I promise I didn't copy ;-)

Comment: @RHertel Ahah, of course you didn't, no problem at all :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since R does not use any distinct character to designate the end of a command (like, e.g., `;` in C or C++), the parser needs to have a way to know when a line is completed and when it isn't.

To resolve the matter you could just place the `%>%` operator at the end of the previous line instead of putting it at the beginning of the next:

```
flights %>% group_by(origin, dest) %>% 
  summarise(total = sum(flight))
```